# How to specify Postgres in AWS Aurora using Cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-aurora

I'm trying to launch a Postgres-flavor Aurora cluster using Cloudformation, but I can't find how to specify "postgres" in the template.  Does anyone know how to do it, or is Postgres supported at all?

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-rds-database-instance.html

Comment: I think I've found it, in another doc: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_CreateDBInstance.html

`aurora-postgresql`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**aurora-postgresql**

Currently the only engine version supported is 9.6.3

**UPDATE** - the current supported aurora versions now include 9.6.6, 9.6.8, and 9.6.9
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/rds/describe-db-engine-versions.html

**UPDATE 2** - and for version 10, the current supported aurora versions include postgres: 10.4, 10.5, 10.6
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraPostgreSQL.Updates.20180305.html

```
aws rds describe-db-engine-versions --engine aurora-postgresql
--region us-east-1 {
    "DBEngineVersions": [
        {
            "Engine": "aurora-postgresql",
            "DBParameterGroupFamily": "aurora-postgresql9.6",
            "DBEngineDescription": "Aurora (PostgreSQL)",
            "EngineVersion": "9.6.3",
            "DBEngineVersionDescription": "Aurora PostgreSQL (compatible with PostgreSQL 9.6.3)",
            "ValidUpgradeTarget": []
        }
    ] }
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/APIReference/API_CreateDBInstance.html

Engine

```
The name of the database engine to be used for this instance.

Not every database engine is available for every AWS Region.

Valid Values:

    aurora

    aurora-postgresql

    mariadb

    mysql

    oracle-ee

    oracle-se2

    oracle-se1

    oracle-se

    postgres

    sqlserver-ee

    sqlserver-se

    sqlserver-ex

    sqlserver-web
```

Comment: Thanks, you also solved my trouble of finding the correct parameter group family to use :)